# Will this screwdriver set fit into my corded Bosch GSB 450?

Tags: concrete, walls, wood, screws, drill

I've this [drill](https://www.amazon.in/Bosch-450-Watt-Professional-Impact-Drill/dp/B0873PH133). My aim is to drive screws using this [driver](https://www.amazon.in/Bosch-X30Ti-Drill-Driver-30-Pieces/dp/B000P4KR5E) (not really worried about the drill bits, those are just bonus)

I've seen numerous videos on YouTube but all use the holder end (screenshot below) on cordless drill machines.

[image]

This makes me wonder if I can make that part (circled above) fit into my corded machine.

Comment: The tip holder should fit the drill just fine, but many tip holders have provisions to secure the tip into the holder that interferes with hex heads from seating well into the tip

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely can. In the professional world that's the standard, in fact.

Your drill can accept any round or hexagonal bit or driver up to 10mm in diameter. It's not fussy. Chucks don't vary between corded and cordless tools, generally speaking.

Comment: Chucks don't vary, but level of control certainly does. I don't think I have ever seen a corded drill that was suitable for use as a screwdriver.

Comment: @PeterGreen - I have all corded power tools. Two of them are drill like tools that are specifically made for driving screws. Their gear box has a different gear ratio so they run slower with a lot more torque.

Answer (score 0):

Will it fit? almost certainly. Is it a good idea? probably not.

Most modern regular drills* have a 3 jaw chuck which will grip round or hexagonal objects in a wide variety of sizes. While I can't see the jaws of the chuck in your photo I would be extremely surprised if it was not such a chuck.

The problem with using a corded drill as a screwdriver is that most corded drills have no torque control and very crude speed control. This means it is easy to either damage the screwhead/bit or in some cases drive the screwhead through the material.

* There are also SDS+ drills but you would know if you had one of those.

Comment: You're right. My chuck has a 3 jaws that tighten around the bit. Something like this https://www.amazon.in/Bosch-2608571079-Drill-Chuck-Key/dp/B00LW4GYO4

I do acknowledge that drawback that you have mentioned with respect to corded machines, but buying a cordless one is out of my budget at the moment.

Comment: My Bosch corded drill, with hammer option, has superb low speed control. Puts in long 10” screws like a dream, does not make fixing insultion less boring though.

Comment: I ran tens of thousands of screws into decking, furniture, and many other things before cordless drills became an option. It takes a slightly different skill set, but to say it's a _problem_ is hyperbolic.